# Проблема с if elif aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

```py
@dp.message(Command('cifra'))
async def cmd_dice(message: types.Message):
    import random
    rndm = str(random.randint(1, 2))
    z=1
    n=2
    if rndm = z:
        await message.answer("1" + rndm)
    elif rndm = n:
        await message.reply("ваше число 2" + rndm)
```

Что не так в этом куске кода?
Мне нужно вывести определенное сообщение при определенном результате
Т.е рандом выдает число 2 и выводится сообщений "ваше число 2",а если число 1 - выводится сообщение "ваше число 1".
Думаю, суть ясна =D

Comment: `=` -> `==`....

Comment: Неа, почему-то все равно не работает

Comment: @wchistow, код из вопроса вообще разве не с синтаксической ошибкой? https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v0LBVsGQKzNNAcQwslIoSCwu5iooyswr0ajQ/P8fAA

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

`=` - это присваивание, а сравнение это `==`

У вас же получается что в **if** вы присваиваете переменной **rndm** значение из переменно **z**. И такая операция всегда возвращает *true*, а значит всегда выполняется первое условие.

Плюс ко всему вы зачем-то конвертируете число, которое вам вернула функция **randint** в строку, а потом эту строку сравниваете с числом.

Comment: @dp.message(Command('cifra'))
async def cmd_dice(message: types.Message):
    import random
    rndm = str(random.randint(1, 2))
    z=1
    n=2
    if rndm == z:
        await message.answer("1" + rndm)
    elif rndm == n:
        await message.reply("ваше число 2" + rndm)


Так должно это выглядеть?

Comment: ой,все,понял о чем Вы,СПАСИБО!

Comment: В питоне в if'е присваивание будет `:=`, а не просто `=`. Одинарное равество даёт синтаксическую ошибку: https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v0LBVsGQKzNNAcQwslIoSCwu5iooyswr0ajQ/P8fAA

Answer (score 1):

В переменной **rndm** у вас храниться строковая 1 или 2, чему свидетельствует **str**

`rndm = str(random.randint(1, 2))`

Чтобы получить ожидаемый результат вы можете воспользоваться следующим кодом

```
from random import randint
rand_int = randint(1, 2)
if rand_int == 1:
    await message.answer('Вам выпало 1')
else:
    await message.answer('Вам выпало 2')
```